# Смещение блока в зависимости от вложенного контента

Tags: javascript, css, html5, css3, responsive

Как более правильно смещать wrapper так что бы ch2 всегда был по центру страницы?
ch1 и ch3 содержат текст который может изменяться
ch2 картинка

[image: визуализация]

Первый вариант который пришел в голову, скриптом считывать позицию ch2 и относительно этих значений смещать wrapper.

Comment: А ширина ch2 известная?

Comment: да, 180px, но для таблеток может уменьшаться.

Comment: Каких таблеток?

Comment: Для всех планшетов, этот вариант будет использоваться с разрешения от 768пх или 900пх.

Comment: Тогда лучше скриптом

Answer (score 0):

Вот пример реализации на css. Для планшетов уменьшаешь ширину блока block-wrapper и соответственно left для block-3 и right для block-1

```css
#block-wrapper{
  width: 180px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}
#block-1{
  position: absolute;
  width: 220px;
  height: 30px;
  top: 0;
  right: 190px;
  background: red;
 }

#block-2{
  height: 30px;
  background: red;
 }  

#block-3{
  position: absolute;
  width: 120px;
  height: 30px;
  top: 0;
  left: 190px;
  background: red;
 }
```

```html
<div id="block-wrapper">
  <div id="block-1"></div>
  <div id="block-2"></div>
  <div id="block-3"></div>
</div>
```